# In PIE binary, code section changes during execution. Why this happens?

Tags: assembly, x86, binary, loader, position-independent-code

Due to the nature of the PIE binary, all data in binary cannot be accessed by ***absolute*** address.
So, there are two ways to access the data ***relatively***

***TWO Way***

1. During execution, *loader* loads the data's location at `GOT` entry.
   And binary access to that address.
2. Calculate the address of data using `_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE` location, and access to it.

But, I saw another way to access data relatively.
In below binary, binary changed `<.text>` section's code.
It was very weird.

```
.global main
main:
 push stderr
```

I compiled it into pie binary.

```
jiwon@jiwon$ gcc -fPIE -pie -o test test.s
jiwon@jiwon$ objdump -D test_pie | grep "<main>" -A5
000005c0 <main>:
 5c0:   ff 35 00 00 00 00       pushl  0x0
 5c6:   66 90                   xchg   %ax,%ax
 5c8:   66 90                   xchg   %ax,%ax
 5ca:   66 90                   xchg   %ax,%ax
```

As you can see above disassembly, `push stderr` assembled into `pushl  0x0`.
And.. When I execute the binary,

```
pwndbg> disass /r main
Dump of assembler code for function main:
=> 0x004005c0 <+0>: ff 35 48 18 40 00   push   DWORD PTR ds:0x401848
   0x004005c6 <+6>: 66 90   xchg   ax,ax
   0x004005c8 <+8>: 66 90   xchg   ax,ax
   0x004005ca <+10>:    66 90   xchg   ax,ax
```

The <.text> section changed to point the `stderr`!
I think It's very weird because `<.text>` section has `-WX` permission in general application.
But In this case, `<.text>` is `RWX` permission.

***Question:***

1. Why this happens? 
   Why compiler choose to use this weird way, instead of above ***TWO Way***?
2. Is this common situation in *pie* binary..?

Comment: It's just relocation. That's the actual way to access data if you don't generate PIC and the address can fit into an immediate.

Comment: Use `objdump -drRwC` to show relocations, including shared-library relocations like PIE uses.  But yes, 32-bit code doesn't have RIP-relative addressing available, so it needs relocation fixups when loaded, or highly inconvenient methods for making position-independent code.  I'd recommend against making 32-bit PIE executables, use `gcc -no-pie -fno-pie -m32`.

Answer (score 0):

Position independent executable is produced by combined work of compiler and linker, not just by the linker. In your case, you passed `GCC` an already assembled code, probably not what the compiler would have produced with the `PIE` flag.

The linker is not the one who produces relative load and store instructions, the compiler does that, and the linker makes sure proper relocation sections are placed correctly and such.